# Creating a dynamic hover map using an interactive Lottie animation

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, lottie

I'm wondering if it is possible to create an interactive Lottie animation that can work just like this SVG hover map example here:

```js
var svg = document.querySelector("svg");
var paths = document.querySelectorAll("path.state");

var i = paths.length;
while(i--) {
  paths[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function(e) {
    svg.appendChild(e.target);
  });
}
```

```css
.state {
fill:white;
stroke:dodgerblue;
transform-origin: center center;
transform-box: fill-box;
transition:  0.3s;
}

:hover.state {
 fill:blue;
 stroke:white;
 stroke-width:2px;
 filter:url(#dropshadow);
 -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
 transform: scale(1.1);
 
 }
```

```html
   <section id="map">

    <svg version="1.1"
       id="svg2" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="467 -284 959 593" xml:space="preserve">
   <defs>
    <filter id="dropshadow" height="130%">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3"/> 
      <feOffset dx="2" dy="2" result="offsetblur"/> 
      <feMerge> 
        <feMergeNode/>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/> 
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs>      
      <g>
      <title>"ID" - IDAHO
      State capital city - Boise
      Population - 228,790
      </title>
      <path id="ID"  class="state" d="
        M615.5-107.5l8.8-35.2l1.4-4.2l2.5-5.9l-1.3-2.3l-2.5,0.1l-0.8-1l0.5-1.1l0.3-3.1l4.5-5.5l1.8-0.5l1.1-1.1l0.6-3.2l0.9-0.7l3.9-5.8
        l3.9-4.3l0.2-3.8l-3.4-2.6l-1.5-4.4l13.6-63.3l13.5,2.5l-4.4,21.4l3.6,7.5l-1.6,4.7l2,4.6l3.1,1.3l3.8,9.6l3.5,4.4l0.5,1.1l3.3,1.1
        l0.4,2.1l-7,17.4l-0.2,2.6l2.6,3.3l0.9,0l4.9-3l0.7-1.1l1.6,0.7l-0.3,5.4l2.7,12.6l3.9,3.2l1.7,2.2l-0.7,4.1l1.1,2.8l1.1,1.1
        l2.5-2.4l2.8,0l2.9,1.3l2.8-0.7l3.8-0.2l4,1.6l2.7-0.3l0.5-3l2.9-0.8l1.3,1.5l0.4,2.9l1.4,1.2l-8.4,53.6
        C710.4-89.3,622.5-106,615.5-107.5z"/> 
        </g>
  <g>    
    <title>   "UT" - Utah
      State capital city - Salt Lake City
      Population
      City  186,440
      Estimate Estimate (2018)  200,591
      </title>
      <path id="UT"  class="state" d="M726.5,26.1l-83.7-11.9
        l20.6-112.5l46.8,8.7l-1.5,10.6l-2.3,13.2l7.8,0.9l16.4,1.8l8.2,0.9L726.5,26.1z"/>
</g>
      <g>    
    <title>   "AZ" - Arizona
      State capital city - Phoenix
      Population
      City  1,445,632
      Estimate Estimate (2018)  1,660,272
      </title>
      <path id="AZ" class="state" d="
        M611.9,98.6l-2.6,2.2l-0.3,1.5l0.5,1l18.9,10.7l12.1,7.6l14.7,8.6l16.8,10l12.3,2.4l25,2.7l17.3-119.1l-83.7-11.9l-3.1,16.4l-1.6,0
        l-1.7,2.6l-2.5-0.1l-1.3-2.7l-2.7-0.3l-0.9-1.1H628l-0.9,0.6l-1.9,1l-0.1,7l-0.2,1.7l-0.6,12.6l-1.5,2.2l-0.6,3.3l2.7,4.9l1.3,5.8
        l0.8,1l1,0.6l-0.1,2.3l-1.6,1.4l-3.4,1.7l-1.9,1.9l-1.5,3.7l-0.6,4.9l-2.9,2.7l-2.1,0.7l0.1,0.8l-0.5,1.7l0.5,0.8l3.7,0.6l-0.6,2.7
        l-1.5,2.2L611.9,98.6z"/>
</g>        
<g>    
    <title>   "NV" - Nevada
      State capital city - Carson City
      Population
      City  55,274
      Estimate Estimate (2018)  55,414
      </title>
      <path id="NV" class="state" d="M663.4-98.4
        L639.8,30.4l-1.8,0.3l-1.6,2.4l-2.4,0l-1.5-2.7l-2.6-0.4l-0.8-1.1l-1-0.1l-2.8,1.6l-0.3,6.8l-0.4,5.8l-0.3,8.6l-1.4,2.1l-2.4-1.1
        L551.3-51.5l19-67.6L663.4-98.4z"/>
</g>        
<g>    
    <title>   "OR" - Oregon
      State capital city - Salem
      Population
      City  154,637
      Estimate Estimate (2018)  173,442
      </title>
      <path id="OR" class="state" d="
        M615.7-108.5l8.9-34.8l1.1-4.2l2.4-5.6l-0.6-1.2l-2.5,0l-1.3-1.7l0.5-1.5l0.5-3.2l4.5-5.5l1.8-1.1l1.1-1.1l1.5-3.6l4-5.7l3.6-3.9
        l0.2-3.5l-3.3-2.5l-1.8-4.6l-12.7-3.6l-15.1-3.5l-15.4,0.1l-0.5-1.4l-5.5,2.1l-4.5-0.6l-2.4-1.6l-1.3,0.7l-4.7-0.2l-1.7-1.4
        l-5.3-2.1l-0.8,0.1l-4.3-1.5l-1.9,1.8l-6.2-0.3l-5.9-4.1l0.7-0.8l0.2-7.8l-2.3-3.9l-4.1-0.6l-0.7-2.5l-2.4-0.5l-5.8,2.1l-2.3,6.5
        l-3.2,10l-3.2,6.5l-5,14.1l-6.5,13.6l-8.1,12.6l-1.9,2.9l-0.8,8.6l0.4,12.1L615.7-108.5z"/>
</g>     
     <g>
      <title>   "WA" - Washington Territory
      State capital city - Olympia
      Population
      City  46,478
      Estimate (2018)   52,555
      </title>
      <path id="WA" class="state" class="state" d="
        M569.1-276.4l4.4,1.5l9.7,2.7l8.6,1.9l20,5.7l23,5.7l15.2,3.2l-13.6,63.6l-12.4-3.5l-15.5-3.6l-15.2,0l-0.5-1.3l-5.6,2.2l-4.6-0.7
        l-2.1-1.6L579-200l-4.7-0.1l-1.7-1.3l-5.3-2.1l-0.7,0.1l-4.4-1.5l-1.9,1.8l-6.3-0.3l-5.9-4.1l0.8-0.9l0.1-7.7l-2.3-3.8l-4.1-0.6
        l-0.7-2.5l-2.3-0.5l-3.6,1.2l-2.3-3.2l0.3-2.9l2.7-0.3l1.6-4l-2.6-1.1l0.2-3.7l4.4-0.6l-2.7-2.7l-1.5-7.1l0.6-2.9v-7.9l-1.8-3.2
        l2.3-9.4l2.1,0.5l2.4,2.9l2.7,2.6l3.2,1.9l4.5,2.1l3.1,0.6l2.9,1.5l3.4,1l2.3-0.2v-2.4l1.3-1.1l2.1-1.3l0.3,1.1l0.3,1.8l-2.3,0.5
        l-0.3,2.1l1.8,1.5l1.1,2.4l0.6,1.9l1.5-0.2l0.2-1.3l-1-1.3l-0.5-3.2l0.8-1.8l-0.6-1.5v-2.3l1.8-3.6l-1.1-2.6l-2.4-4.9l0.3-0.8
        L569.1-276.4z M559.6-270.4l2-0.2l0.5,1.4l1.5-1.6h2.3l0.8,1.5l-1.5,1.7l0.6,0.8l-0.7,2l-1.4,0.4c0,0-0.9,0.1-0.9-0.2
        s1.5-2.6,1.5-2.6l-1.7-0.6l-0.3,1.5l-0.7,0.6l-1.5-2.3L559.6-270.4z"/>
  </g> 
  <g>
      <title>   "CA" - California
      State capital city - Sacramento
      Population
      City  466,488
      Estimate (2018)   508,529
      </title>
      <path id="CA" class="state" d="
        M611.7,98.2l3.9-0.5l1.5-2l0.5-2.9l-3.6-0.6l-0.5-0.7l0.5-2l-0.2-0.6l1.9-0.6l3-2.8l0.6-5l1.4-3.4l1.9-2.2l3.5-1.6l1.7-1.6l0.1-2.1
        l-1-0.6l-1-1.1l-1.2-5.8l-2.7-4.8l0.6-3.5l-2.4-1L551.3-51.5l18.9-67.6l-67.1-15.7l-1.5,4.7l-0.2,7.4l-5.2,11.8l-3.1,2.6l-0.3,1.1
        l-1.8,0.8l-1.5,4.2l-0.8,3.2l2.7,4.2l1.6,4.2l1.1,3.6l-0.3,6.5l-1.8,3.1l-0.6,5.8l-1,3.7l1.8,3.9l2.7,4.5l2.3,4.9l1.3,4l-0.3,3.2
        l-0.3,0.5v2.1l5.7,6.3l-0.5,2.4l-0.6,2.3l-0.6,1.9l0.2,8.2l2.1,3.7l1.9,2.6l2.7,0.5l1,2.7l-1.1,3.6l-2.1,1.6h-1.1l-0.8,3.9l0.5,2.9
        l3.2,4.4l1.6,5.3l1.5,4.7l1.3,3.1l3.4,5.8l1.5,2.6l0.5,2.9l1.6,1v2.4l-0.8,1.9l-1.8,7.1l-0.5,1.9l2.4,2.7l4.2,0.5l4.5,1.8l3.9,2.1
        h2.9l2.9,3.1l2.6,4.9l1.1,2.3l3.9,2.1l4.8,0.8l1.5,2.1l0.6,3.2l-1.5,0.6l0.3,1l3.2,0.8l2.7,0.2l3.2-1.7l3.9,4.2l0.8,2.3l2.6,4.2
        l0.3,3.2v9.4l0.5,1.8l10,1.5l19.7,2.7L611.7,98.2z M523.6,54.5l1.3,1.5l-0.2,1.3l-3.2-0.1l-0.6-1.2l-0.6-1.5L523.6,54.5z
         M525.5,54.5l1.2-0.6l3.6,2.1l3.1,1.2l-0.9,0.6l-4.5-0.2l-1.6-1.6L525.5,54.5z M546.2,74.3l1.8,2.3l0.8,1l1.5,0.6l0.6-1.5l-1-1.8
        l-2.7-2l-1.1,0.2V74.3z M544.7,82.9l1.8,3.2l1.2,1.9l-1.5,0.2l-1.3-1.2c0,0-0.7-1.5-0.7-1.9s0-2.2,0-2.2L544.7,82.9z"/>
        </g>
    </svg>

  </section>
```

I know that you can trigger an animation to run on hover but is it possible to set it up so that different areas of the animation can animate on hover as in the map example I showed above?

Thank you,
Jason O

Comment: I don't get it. Would you like to make the hover effect on each state work properly or is the map just and example and you would like to do something completely different? If the later then try share with us what it is that you would like to create.

Comment: What I want to know is if I could implement the above animation effects directly with a Lottie animation instead of coding the SVG map like in the example above. If so, I would like to be able to do more complex animation transition effects when the map elements are hovered over.